# Removing Malware

Tags: post-meta, sql

I've been asked to remove some Malware from a friend's site.

I've found some wonky links in the `wp_postmeta` table, but the `post_id` that the field is associated with doesn't exist - and, weirdly, it's way too high. I think the fields have the `meta_key` that starts with `_feedback_`

What is the easiest way to search the `meta_value` on those fields (seems to be JSON?) and delete the bad ones?

I found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/164096/is-removing-orphaned-wp-postmeta-records-safe/257279#257279) that suggested:

```
DELETE * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts)
```

But when I ran (with updated table names) I got 0 results, which I feel shouldn't happen?

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts)
```

Comment: But you genuinely do have an example of a postmeta row whose post doesn't exist in wp_posts? Maybe try selecting wp_postmeta where post_id = that, and double check selecting that ID from wp_posts. Without your data I'm not sure we can help you debug this.

Comment: (P.S. it's just `DELETE FROM` not `DELETE * FROM`)